# Is there any way to perform 3D-FFT and 3D-IFFT using C# the same as fftn() in matlab?

Tags: c#, fft

I Want to perform 3D-FFT and 3D-IFFT using C#. The fftn() in MATLAB works well, but I want to write a software using C#. I don't find any Free Library do the same thing in C#. Could anyone help?

I have tried Math.net, WFFT.Net. None of them work. Maybe ILNumberic can help but it is not free. I wrote An algorithm to perform 3D-FFT and 3D-IFFT through 1D-FFT. But it was too slow. It used 2 second to perform a 64x64x1000 point 3D-FFT but MATLAB only used 0.2 second.

```
        static Complex[,,] Fft3D(float[,,] data)
        {
            int M = data.GetLength(0);
            int N = data.GetLength(1);
            int K = data.GetLength(2);
            Complex[,,] data3D = new Complex[M, N, K];
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        data3D[i, j, k] = new Complex(data[i, j, k], 0.0);
                    }
                }
            }          
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {                   
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[K];
                    for(int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        data1D[k] = data3D[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Forward(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        data3D[i, j, k] = data1D[k];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                {
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[N];
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        data1D[j] = data3D[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Forward(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        data3D[i, j, k] = data1D[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                {
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[M];
                    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                    {
                        data1D[i] = data3D[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Forward(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                    {
                        data3D[i, j, k] = data1D[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            return data3D;
        }
        static float[,,] Ifft3D(Complex[,,] data)
        {
            int M = data.GetLength(0);
            int N = data.GetLength(1);
            int K = data.GetLength(2);
            float[,,] data3D = new float[M, N, K];
            Complex[,,] dataCopy = (Complex[,,])data.Clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[K];
                    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        data1D[k] = dataCopy[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Inverse(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        dataCopy[i, j, k] = data1D[k];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                {
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[N];
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        data1D[j] = dataCopy[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Inverse(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                    {
                        dataCopy[i, j, k] = data1D[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                {
                    Complex[] data1D = new Complex[M];
                    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                    {
                        data1D[i] = dataCopy[i, j, k];
                    }
                    Fourier.Inverse(data1D, FourierOptions.Matlab);
                    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                    {
                        dataCopy[i, j, k] = data1D[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                    {
                        data3D[i, j, k] = (float)dataCopy[i, j, k].Real;
                    }
                }
            }
            return data3D;
        }
```

Comment: The input is an array of float[64,64,1000].It used 2 second while matlab do the same thing using 0.2 second.

Comment: FFTW, FFTPack and pocketFFT are the go-to free open-source libraries for general FFTs. I’m sure you can use those from within C#.

Comment: A 10-times difference is not to bad, compared to some highly optimized code. Note that multi dimensional indexing will need to do something like `i * N * M+j * N + k`, and I would not be sure the compiler could optimize and hoist parts of this outside the loop. So it might be faster to use a 1D array and write the indexing yourself. Also, Do some profiling, you will likely find some things that could be improved..